# Update user profile in firebase on being connected

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Below is the Firebase sample code, where I can update a user after being authenticated. (var user = firebase.auth (). currentUser;)

```
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

I would like to know if it is possible to edit the user without having to be logged in, use the updateProfile function with the user's UID or EMAIL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user cannot successfully call `updateProfile` unless they're logged in.  Anything else would be a massive security hole, since that means anyone on the internet would be able to update any profile with only knowledge of a UID.

Comment: I understand and agree. But imagine that in my app there is an administrator panel and in that panel I have the list of my customers, is there not a way in which I can edit my customer's profile without having to connect to his account?

Comment: You would need to use a backend with the Firebase Admin SDK to work with user accounts like this.  You won't be able to do it on the frontend only.